# Browser auto reload when code changes angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2019

I created a new Angular with Core project in Visual Studio 2019.
Browser is not auto reloading when I made code changes. It requires hard refresh after every code change.
Anyone can please help me to resolve my issue?

**package.json settings:**

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

Comment: which angular version your using ?

Comment: I am using Angular 12.2.0

Comment: have you try it with vs code ?

Comment: No. My requirement is Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Change "start": "ng serve" to "start": "ng serve --live-reload"